# Solution of the differential equation $2x^3dy + (1 - y^2)(x^2y^2 + y^2 - 1)dx = 0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the solution of the differential equation 
>   $$2x^3dy + (1 - y^2)(x^2y^2 + y^2 - 1)dx = 0$$

**My attempt:** After arranging the above equation as $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{(1-y^2)(x^2y^2+y^2-1)}{-2x^3}$$ I am not getting any standard method to get to the next step. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: @MyGlasses I rechecked the question and found no change. The term is given as $2x^3dy$

Comment: From what the ODE $2x^3dy + (1 - y^2)(x^2y^2 + y^2 - 1)dx = 0$ is coming ? Would you mind to write the orignal wording of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$2x^3~dy+(1-y^2)(x^2y^2+y^2-1)dx=0$

$2x^3~dy=(y^2-1)(x^2y^2+y^2-1)dx$

$(x^2y^2+y^2-1)\dfrac{dx}{dy}=\dfrac{2x^3}{y^2-1}$

Let $u=\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{dy}=-\dfrac{2}{x^3}\dfrac{dx}{dy}$

$\therefore-\dfrac{(x^2y^2+y^2-1)x^3}{2}\dfrac{du}{dy}=\dfrac{2x^3}{y^2-1}$

$\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{y^2-1}\right)\dfrac{du}{dy}=-\dfrac{4}{(y^2-1)^2x^2}$

$\left(u+\dfrac{y^2}{y^2-1}\right)\dfrac{du}{dy}=-\dfrac{4u}{(y^2-1)^2}$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Let $v=u+\dfrac{y^2}{y^2-1}$ ,

Then $u=v-\dfrac{y^2}{y^2-1}$

$\dfrac{du}{dy}=\dfrac{dv}{dy}+\dfrac{2y}{(y^2-1)^2}$

$\therefore v\left(\dfrac{dv}{dy}+\dfrac{2y}{(y^2-1)^2}\right)=-\dfrac{4}{(y^2-1)^2}\left(v-\dfrac{y^2}{y^2-1}\right)$

$v\dfrac{dv}{dy}+\dfrac{2yv}{(y^2-1)^2}=-\dfrac{4v}{(y^2-1)^2}+\dfrac{4y^2}{(y^2-1)^3}$

$v\dfrac{dv}{dy}=-\dfrac{2(y+2)v}{(y^2-1)^2}+\dfrac{4y^2}{(y^2-1)^3}$